# error: incorrect depth (!=CV_8U) in function detectAndCompute

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, opencv

I am trying to extract `SIFT` features. I have my image in a `numpy` array (numpy.ndarray), and the values of image is normalized between 0 and 1.

once I reach to this code :

```
 kp, desc = sift.detectAndCompute(gray_img, None)
```

It is showing the following error:

```
error: /tmp/build/80754af9/opencv_1512680317074/work/opencv_contrib-3.3.1/modules/xfeatures2d/src/sift.cpp:1116: error: (-5) image is empty or has incorrect depth (!=CV_8U) in function detectAndCompute
```

Could someone please help me with this, what is the reason?

Thanks

Comment: You have to carefully read your error message. it expects a `CV_8U` but your normalized data is probably `CV_32F`. You can define how you want to read your data on opening.

Comment: @user1767754 Thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: How did you resolve this error? Im also facing the issue.